# terminology needed

Tags: general-topology, terminology

This is just a terminology question.  Let $Y$ be a topological space.  Is there a word to describe those topological spaces $X$ that contain $Y$ as a dense subspace?  If not, what would you call such spaces $X$? The idea is that I want $Y$ dense in $X$ as a property of $X$ with respect to $Y$ as opposed to $Y$ with respect to $X$.  So you might say $X$ is *blank* over $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean with the properties remarks at the end, but spaces $Y$ in which $X$ embeds as a dense subspace are sometimes called "extensions" of $X$. Special cases are compactifications and connectifications (where $Y$ is also demanded to be compact or connected resp.)

A book that treats extensions in some generality (mostly in dimension theory) is [dimension and extensions](http://www.elsevier.com/books/dimension-and-extensions/aarts/978-0-444-89740-4) by Aarts and Nishiura.

In respond to the comment that an extension is just any space $Y$ that contains $X$: in that case the relation to $X$ becomes very slim indeed. We can just take any space $Z$ and form a disjoint sum of $X$ and $Z$ to get all sorts of "extensions" in this sense. I think the denseness condition is usually assumed in the term extension: we should be able to "reach" points of the larger space via $X$, so to speak.

Comment: To me an "extension" of $X$ would simply be a space $Y$ containing $X$. I'm looking for a word to modify the word "extension" that could signify that $Y$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: The problem is I need to use the term in an algebra context rather than topology specifically, where extensions are defined more broadly.  With your terminology applied here, the completion of a ring with respect to an ideal would just be a unique "complete extension" in the appropriate sense, which is not standard terminology.  Put another way, would you call a topological ring $S$ containing a topological ring $R$ as a dense subring a "complete extension" of $R$, or would that rather mean a complete topological ring containing $R$ as a topological subring?